# Data Warehouse: Can a Transaction Table also be a Dimension?

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, sql-server-2017

We have a transaction table. Not only does sales team want to analyze by CustomerId or Productid sold, but also by sales amount sold or quantities.
Kimball states, a fact table here can also be a dimension. In that case, could I leave by transaction table as a large dimension table? Just want to understand Kimballs article below.

https://www.kimballgroup.com/2007/12/design-tip-97-modeling-data-as-both-a-fact-and-dimension-attribute/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `amount sold` and `quantities sold` directly relate to a transaction and I would think those items should be in a transaction fact table and not on a dimension.

If quantities are especially interesting (e.g., enough to have a hierarchy), one might create a dimension for it, in addition to the `Quantity` field in the fact table. Such an `OrderSize` dimension could have fields like `QuantityBand` with values like "1 to 10" and "11 to 50", and `QuantityDiscount`.

> Can a Transaction Table also be a Dimension?

The answer is yes, it can. Should it? Probably no, but dependent columns are not unheard of. Just know that you are wasting tons of space with repeating columns. Also, the term is Dimensions vs Fact tables. Dimension tables describe the data while Fact tables describe what they are doing.

*<sub>answer based on comments left by [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin), [clifton_h](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/105012/clifton-h), and [Jon of All Trades](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1896/jon-of-all-trades)</sub>*